# Is 'intricated' a valid word?

Tags: word-request

I've Googled 'intricated', but it's suggested 'intricate' instead. Also my browser highlights this word.

On the other hand I can find it on [wiktionary](https://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/intricated) page:

> simple past tense and past participle of intricate

So is this word exists? Can I say that *page/post or something was intricated*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, *intricated* is the simple past of the verb *to intricate*.

Note that the *Oxford English Dictionary* says the word is used less than 1 time per million words in modern English. In other words, most people would not know what you mean, because the word is rarely used as a verb.

Answer (score 2):

The dictionary meaning of the adjective "intricate" is to have complexity.

The dictionary meaning of the verb "intricate" is to enmesh or entangle.

I'd not expect many people to infer the verb meaning. If you want to be understood don't use intricate as a verb.